# Can I use a .75 HP inverter drive in place of a .5 HP one?

Tags: tolerance, ratings, drive

I am trying to replace some .5 HP 3-phase AC 240V motor drives with a different brand. The new brand doesn't seem to offer a .5 HP variant. Would the .75 HP variant work?

Edit: A little twist -- the motor itself seems to be 1/3 HP.

Edit 2: Realized I'm probably going to be replacing the motor as well, so probably a moot point for now.

Comment: Typically, yes.  The motor is only so much of a load, so powering it from a bigger drive just presents less load to the drive.

Comment: Most VFDs require entry of parameters to match the motor. Why not include a link to the manual in your question?

Comment: Have you read the manual? Is the motor you are using rated to use with an inverter drive? Generally smaller in HP is OK.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble digging up the actual manuals for the motors in question.

Comment: The inverter manual should cover this configuration.

Comment: Even though some motors are not explicitly rated for inverter drive, that doesn't mean they won't work with an inverter. It would be worth reading technical literature on the topic to gain a greater understanding of the issue. The most obvious and immediate issue is that some motors will overheat if run at low speed and full torque, because the built-in centrifugal fan runs at shaft speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost always use a slightly larger VFD in place of a smaller one. A 750 W (1 HP) VFD can probably drive a 250 W (1/3 HP) motor, for example. But you should read the manual for the VFD for confirmation before committing to the purchase. If you purchase a no-name VFD with no manual or support available, then you are taking your chances. VFD's in this size range are not that expensive, so there is not much reason to buy no-name items.

Answer (score 2):

You most certainly can.

Don't forget to lower the nominal motor current setting in the inverter though.